# Any one gotten SwiftUI SignInWithAppleButton to work on tvOS

Tags: swiftui, tvos, sign-in-with-apple

I am trying to use the SignInWithAppleButton for SwiftUI to work with tvOS? I am getting an issue where the request and completion blocks are not being called and there is no error in any log that I can find. It just animates the click and that is it. This has been tested on an actual Apple TV with tvOS 14.

My code is a simple page:

```
import SwiftUI
import AuthenticationServices

struct SignInView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            Text("Welcome to My App")
                .font(.system(size: 50.0, weight: .bold))

            SignInWithAppleButton(.signIn) { request in
                request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
            } onCompletion: { result in
                print(result)
            }
            .signInWithAppleButtonStyle(.whiteOutline)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
        }
        
    }
}
```

I don't see the result or request blocks getting called at all.

Comment: What is "SignOnWithAppleButton"?  You mean 'SignInWithAppleButton'?  Show what you have done in code unless you are looking for a spiritual encouragement.

Comment: I have added the code..

Comment: Do you test it with an actual device?

Comment: Yes on an actual TV.. I know I can't do this in the emulator.

Comment: I think it's a bug.  I get 'Unknown class _TtC18SwiftUIAppleSignIn14ViewController in Interface Builder file' with my iPhone.

Comment: This is SwiftUI not UIKit. It works in the iPhone/iPad project.

Comment: I happen to know that.  I am deaf but not blind.  I was playing the same lines of code with SwiftUI two days before.

Comment: I saw interface builder and that in my head says UIKit. Sorry and don't snap.